# About Bessel^3 integral

Tags: bessel-functions

Consider the damped wave equation in 2 dimensions

$$u_{tt}+b(x,y)u_{t}=u_{xx}+u_{yy}$$

where $b(x)$ is not necessarily constant.

One way to try to understand it is to go to polar coordinates, assume that there is no angular dependence and write the solution as a sum of Bessel's functions.

In particular, we could also try to expand the damping $b(r)$ as a sum of Bessel's functions, and try to find some formula for the coefficients using the orthogonality property.

This leads us to the integral

$$\int_{0}^{1}J_{0}(\alpha_{0i}r)J_{0}(\alpha_{0j}r)J_{0}(\alpha_{0k}r)rdr$$

where $J_{0}$ is that Bessel function of first kind, and $\alpha_{0j}$ is its $j$th root.

If we could express it analitically as a function of $i,j,k$, we would have an expression realting the coefficients of the damping expansion with the coefficients of the position expansion.

After some search, I could not find any formula for it, I would appreciate if someone has a tip on how to proceed from here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you need an exact closed form answer? This is not so bad to compute numerically, even to very high precision.

Comment: Yes, numerically it is not hard to compute it, but an analytical formula would be ideal. I edited my question so it is clearer.